# Bathtub Faucet - Can't stop the water

Tags: bathroom, water, shower, faucet

I don't know what is the part called, but it is supposed to divert the water to the shower head. As shown in the photo, it is in the fully up position, however, large amount of water still coming out of the faucet. Can it be fixed, or I need a new faucet?

[image]

Comment: Is this a new problem or has it always been like this? Is it NOT diverting the water to the shower head properly? I ask because some tub-spout diverters are not designed to shut off the water completely and will always allow a *trickle* of water.

Comment: Let's see up inside. I'd bet that the diverter plate is missing or out of alignment.

Comment: It started a trickle year ago, but now you can see it likes water fall. The pressure on the shower has decreased significantly, hard to get my body wet without turning around all time :) I guess either something inside has wear out, or it is out of alignment. Does it have washer inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to turn that brass colored knob counterclockwise and remove it from the stem or have the stem turn too and remove it from the  diverter plate which should then drop out of the spout. Then examine it for any signs of corrosion or cracking. If damaged, a trip to a plumbing supply store might just do the trick for a replacement.

You have to be semi gentle in turning the knob.... you don't want to shear it off, maybe squirt some CLR or vinegar on the stem threads to dissolve any rust/corrosion.

Comment: Should I use a pliers, and how can I get the diverter plate back to its position?

Comment: @r13   You can try pliers but use a piece of cloth so you don't scratch the surface.  A small strap wrench would be ideal.  To get the diverter plate back to its position, just slide it back up the spout and turn the stem until it catches with the diverter plate

Comment: I use a old leather belt when I grab parts I don’t want to scratch. But replacing the diverter.